# Probability of norm of dependent vector elements

Tags: probability, random-matrix, norm, random-projection

Suppose $A^T x=0$ holds for matrix $A \in R^{n \times m}$ and vector $x \in R^n$. Define vector y as:

$y = (S A)^T Sx = 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
(A_{*1})^T S^T S x \\
\vdots \\
(A_{*m})^T S^T S x
\end{array}
\right].
$

Here, $S \in R^{p \times n}$ is a random projection matrix (with iid entries from $\mathcal{N}(0,1/p)$). You see that each element of vector $y$ is an inner product between the projection of $x$ and the projection of each column of $A$.

Now, suppose the probability of each of those inner products being greater than $\epsilon$ is smaller than $\delta$. In this case, what's the probability of $||y||_2$ being greater than $\epsilon \sqrt{m}$? In other words, what's the probability that all elements of $y$ are greater than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Extremely few matrices with *iid* Normal entries will be projection matrices.  Could you explain, then, what you mean by this term "projection matrix"?

Comment: For example, here x belongs to an n-dim space and left-multiplying by A is equivalent to "randomly-projecting" it onto an m-dim space.

Comment: In other words, $A$ is any matrix at all and the term "projection" doesn't otherwise qualify it.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to the question, but if it helps, yeah sure, suppose there's no "projection" in here and S is just a matrix with normal iid entries. 
BTW, in my previous comment, I mistakenly wrote A, but I meant S. So A is any matrix (whose columns are orthogonal to x), and S is the random matrix.

Comment: Any rephrasing that can help you communicate with readers is relevant to the question.  Note, too, that your question as currently asked cannot be answered: there is no definite probability, because you only provide bounds on some quantities. Thus, the best you can hope for would be bounds for the answer. Since obtaining good ones could require substantial work, I suspect most readers with the skills to reply would be interested in knowing the motivation for this question--for otherwise, why should they care to answer it?  How does it arise in a statistical setting?

Comment: The motivation is to understand how random projection changes the norm of a matrix-vector product. This has a wide range of applications from dimensionality reduction to compressed sensing. Now the way that I was looking at it was as follows. We can view a matrix-vector product as a series of inner products, then in this way, we would be interested in the norm of this vector of inner products. There is a concentration inequality which bounds each inner product with some probability (probability comes in because of the random matrix S).

Comment: So I was thinking, now that those vector elements are dependent, is there a way we bound the norm of that vector? Hope this helps.